# network icon on lock screen, group policy

Tags: network, corporate-policy

In an office setting, where it is an open space design, should I ensure that the laptop has 'Do not display network selection UI', enabled? Why or why not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This generally depends on how many networks will be available in that open space design, and if they're open to anyone or protected.

As you mentioned that it is a laptop, is it going to be taken outside of the office? If so, it might make it difficult to log back into unless you're using cached credentials (if it's connected to a DC).

I would recommend user education over locking everything down - advise users that unless they're using a VPN, then any traffic going over a network that isn't yours specifically is open to being intercepted.

In short: I wouldn't, but it entirely depends on if these laptops are being taken out of the office, and if there are non-work networks that are open and available, and if education for security isn't being done in your workplace.